# How to make android app of a existing website?

Tags: android, html

I have a website and now I want to develop an app for my website for android phone.
Initially what i need to do?
I dont have much knowledge about java, but i have good knowledge about HTML5, CSS3, PHP and mysql?
Anyone please tell me initial steps to do.
Thanks

Comment: try phonegap if you have good grasp over html,css and javascript

Comment: can i develop .apk file in phonegap?

Comment: yes..it will be same as normal android app. http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can create a responsive website and can load it into android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Even you can read more about [building web apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Comment: If you create a responsive website, why would you create an app arround it?

Comment: Yes true but as he has mentioned he wants to create an android app, that's why I have mentioned in my answer to load it into web view and can publish app on play store too.

Comment: yes i want to publish app on playstore, but is it compulsary to make my site responsive for making app?

Comment: It's not necessary but if you make it responsive then it would looks much better, accessible and responsive in all the android phone resolutions. Keep one thing in mind while designing or developing web apps that android comes in variety of screen resolutions.

Comment: will it take too much time to convert normal site to responsive?

Comment: That I can't say but it depends on your knowledge!

Comment: i will be new if i decide to work on responsive, by the way thanks